# How to combine multiple ner models to single pipleline in spacy version 3

Tags: spacy

I have trained 3 different NER model on existing model in spacy version 3. i want to combine those three models to a single pipeline in spacy, so i can load the three of them as one model. Can someone please help me on this.Spacy version 3 details are very less can someone please help me.